# OOP design for global constant in java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

So my question is if I have a father class that is related to a son class by composition. Say the father has 1 million sons. Right now I have a global constant called hair color that is the same for all sons. So in my son class there would be a declaration like the following:

```
private final String HAIR_COLOR = "red";
```

My question is would it be better to have the global constant HAIR_COLOR as a public variable in the father class with a getter method in the son class or should I just leave it the way it is right now?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `father has 1 million sons` -> What a Maaaaaaaan he is. ;)

Comment: By "global constant", do you mean public final static member (feel free to interpret that however you want for a father of 1 million...) of the father class, or what?

Comment: Would it be better _for what_?  Saving memory?  Ease of implementation?

Comment: @RohitJain a couple like that in India and we will be doomed lol.

Comment: Another comment, if all have red hair, why is it in the program at all? What's the purpose of the hair color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the best way is the following:

```
public class Father {

    // ...

}

public abstract class AbstractSon extends Father {
    public static final String HAIR_COLOR = "red";

    // ...

}

public class ConcreteSon extends AbstractSon {

    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define the constant in the first place you are going to use it. If only the son class should be aware of it, it's a bad design to put it in the father class.
There is no harm making a constant as public since it's immutable. It make sense to make it private if the constant data is sensitive and you don't want to expose it.

Answer (score 0):

Make an abstract class and declare the HAIR_COLOR in that. And all the son classes would be inherited from that class only.